# Django Compressor error compiling SASS (--scss Invalid Option)

Tags: python, ruby, django, sass

I have an environment setup on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS to run a Django website and it doesn't seem to want to play nice. The environment is as follows:

```
Python      2.6.5  
Django      1.3.1  
Gunicorn    0.13.4  
Supvervisor 3.0  
Nginx       0.7.65  
Varnish     2.1
```

I have the following relevant modules installed for the Django app:

```
django-appconf    0.4.1  
django-compressor 1.1.1  
django-smartagent 0.1.1  
Coffee Script     1.2.0
Sass              3.1.12
```

Everything starts up just fine, but I get the following template error:

`Caught FilterError while rendering: invalid option: --scss`

I've narrowed it down to this list of tuples within my `settings.py` file:

```
(('text/coffeescript', 'coffee --compile --stdio'),
 ('text/less', 'lessc {infile} {outfile}'),
 ('text/x-sass', 'sass {infile} {outfile}'),
 ('text/x-scss', 'sass --scss {infile} {outfile}'))
```

It looks as if the last line is what's causing all this trouble.

I have the SAME setup on Ubuntu 11.10 and it's working just fine. I'm not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Ruby do you have installed? I suspect that you need to upgrade Ruby, as SASS requires `1.8.7` or greater (according to the [SASS Changelog](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_CHANGELOG.html#318)).

Can you confirm your Ruby version, and if it is `< 1.8.7`, try upgrading and see if that sorts out your issue?

**EDIT**: Supposedly, `Ruby 1.8.7` is included in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, according to the [Ubuntu Tech Specs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Server/TechSpecs/1004LTS). That said, you might want to confirm the version of SASS by running:

```
sass -v
```

Just to be absolutely sure…

Comment: You were absolutely correct. I overlooked the version of Ruby. I purged the packaged version and compiled the latest stable build from source. Repeated the above steps and got the proper version. Thank you kindly, sir.