# Yuglify compressor error with django-pipeline

Tags: python, django, node.js, npm, saas

I am using yuglify css compressor to compress css with my **django-pipeline .**

I have installed required packages, gems and npm packages, then precompiled the assets.

but when running python manage.py collectstatic

its saying `Compressor Error:Killed`

What should I do to get rid of this.

I am listing out my packages and gems with version below.

```
node v0.10.32
npm v1.4.28

npm packages:
yuglify 0.1.4
bower 1.3.8

djang0=1.5.5
django-pipeline==1.3.19

gems:
ruby 1.9.3
bootstrap-sass (2.3.2.2)
compass (0.12.2)
dotenv (0.9.0)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django Compressor error compiling SASS (--scss Invalid Option)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919443/django-compressor-error-compiling-sass-scss-invalid-option)